# Adding function to reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My reducer is as follows :

```
const removeFilter = (state, name) => {
    return state.filter(f => f.name !== name);
};

export default function addRemoveFilterReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ADD_FILTER:
            if(!state.some(i => i.name === action.searchFilter.name))
                return [...state, {name: action.searchFilter.name, values: [action.searchFilter.values]}];
            else
                return [...state.filter(f => f.name !== action.searchFilter.name), {name: action.searchFilter.name, values: [action.searchFilter.values]}];

        case REMOVE_FILTER:
            return [...state.filter(f => f.name !== action.searchFilter.name)];
        break;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In else state of ADD_FILTER case and in REMOVE_FILTER case I have the same code : `...state.filter(f => f.name !== action.searchFilter.name)`.

I created a function **remove filter** with that code. How can I now use this function in my cases?

I tried with `return [removeFilter(state, action.searchFilter.name, {name: action.searchFilter.name, values: [action.searchFilter.values]}];` in else state of ADD_FILTER case, but it doesn't work.

Any advice?

UPDATE

The function call :

`return [removeFilter(state, action.searchFilter.name, ......];`

Comment: You forgot the square brackets and the spread operator in your function.

Comment: And more, you don't need the last *break* instruction in *REMOVE_FILTER* as you always return from the function. And even the *else* in *ADD_FILTER* could be removed. As how works the switch, if something jump the *if*, than move to the next *case* instruction.

Comment: I changed it and the problem still exists. If reducer is without function i get `[object]` in console log but if i use function with or without changes i get `[Array[0], Object]`

Comment: According to my second comment, actually you don't need a function, as you could just remove the *else* in case ADD_FILTER. So you don't have code duplicated any more. But if you want to figured out why your function is not working, please update post with the way you call the function.

Comment: I can't remove it, because I need to do something depends on `state.some(i => i.name === action.searchFilter.name)`. The else statement is working like it should.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I figured now that the 2 lines was not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change your code in this way:

```
export default function addRemoveFilterReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ADD_FILTER:
            let nState = state;
            if(state.some(i => i.name === action.searchFilter.name)) {
               nState = state.filter(f => f.name !== action.searchFilter.name);
            }

            return [...nState, {name: action.searchFilter.name, values: [action.searchFilter.values]}];

        case REMOVE_FILTER:
            return state.filter(f => f.name !== action.searchFilter.name);

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Now you have splitted up the remove from the add and the code is much clear than was before.

So on your function now:

```
const removeFilter = (state, name) => {
    return state.filter(f => f.name !== name);
};


export default function addRemoveFilterReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ADD_FILTER:
            let nState = state
            if(state.some(i => i.name === action.searchFilter.name)) {
               nState = removeFilter(state, action.searchFilter.name);
            }

            return [...nState, {name: action.searchFilter.name, values: [action.searchFilter.values]}];

        case REMOVE_FILTER:
            return removeFilter(state, action.searchFilter.name);

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

You already have an array from the function, so you don't need the put it into another array and use the spread operation.

If you need to clone the state object, than do it inside the function, as it is the right place.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In this case nState would always be an empty array if ìf`is false. But I have multiple filters. And most of the time there will be more filters.